# Suggestion for tag synonymous and merger

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

1. [spectrum](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spectrum) -> [frequency spectrum](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frequency-spectrum)
2. [iir](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iir) -> [infinite impulse response](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-impulse-response)

Answer (score 1):

I've done `iir -> infinite impulse response` and merged the two. If you suggest for the first [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tags/frequency-spectrum/synonyms), I'll approve it. Not that I can't set it myself, but you'll get a badge for suggesting (for what it's worth) :)

Comment: Done! I didn't think about the badge though.. :)